# R: Make a loop with different filters

Tags: r, loops

I would like to create a loop in R that would help me analyse a variable according to different filters. I have created a filter list like this:

```
filters <- list(which(df$age<18), which(df$male=="TRUE"),   which(df$age<=5))
```

The problem is that when going from the first filter to the second one, the original values of the variable (which in this case would be 'age') won't go back to the original values and the final results are conditioned to the previous filter.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: If you use the filters for filtering, then there’s usually no reason to use `which`.

Comment: what would be the expected output ? different `data.frames` ?

Comment: Yes, that would be it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a prototype of what I believe you are trying to accomplish:

```
myOutput <- list()

for(i in seq_along(filters)) {
  # get filtered vector
  myVec <- df[filters[[i]], "myVecName"]

  # perform some analysis on myVec
  myOutput[[i]] <- summary(myVec)
}
```

The results of the analysis are then stored in a list called myOutput.

You could accomplish the same with `lapply`:

```
myOutput <- lapply(filters, function(i) summary(df[i, "myVecName"]))
```